# Error: Expected a semicolon . I am creating authentication system using credentials in next auth.I am not being able to fix this syntax error

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, backend

#pages/api/auth
I am creating an authentication system using Nextauth in Next Js. I was following a yt video.The problem seems  to be occuring with authentication using credentials.I checked the syntax time and again but couldnot find anything.
This is the link I was following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFucgPdjeNg&t=436s
I cannot get rid of this error.Please help!

```
import NextAuth,{ NextAuthOptions }  from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
// import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
// import sessionProvider from 'next-auth'
// const client_Id="207449855842-gv24ltosjj4ahf1r7lelc4jiii5qsqe8.apps.googleusercontent.com"
// const client_secret="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"
export default NextAuth({
  
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      client_Id:process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret:process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        // email: { label: "Email address", type: "text" },
        // password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        
          const { email, password } = credentials as {
          email: string;
          password: string;
        };
        if (email !== "john@gmail.com" || password !== "1234") {
          throw new Error("invalid credentials");
        }
        return {
          id: "1234",
          name: "John Doe",
          email: "john@gmail.com",
          role: "admin",
        };
  
       
      }
    }),
    callbacks: {
      jwt(params) {
        // update token
        if (params.user?.role) {
          params.token.role = params.user.role;
        }
        // return final_token
        return params.token;
      },
    },
    session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
    },
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
      
    },
    
  ],
  secret:"[6j2Ld_PiUl3etQENg0swsJnuMaAJ]",
  debug:true
  
   
})
```

ERROR

```
Error:
  x Expected a semicolon
    ,-[C:\Users\acer\Desktop\next\fundraiser\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].js:26:1]
 26 |       },
 27 |       async authorize(credentials, req) {
 28 |
 29 |           const { email, password } = credentials as {
    :                                                   ^^
 30 |           email: string;
 31 |           password: string;
 31 |         };
    `----

  x Expected ',', got ';'
    ,-[C:\Users\acer\Desktop\next\fundraiser\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].js:29:1]
 29 |           const { email, password } = credentials as {
 30 |           email: string;
 31 |           password: string;
 32 |         };
    :          ^
 33 |         if (email !== "john@gmail.com" || password !== "1234") {
 34 |           throw new Error("invalid credentials");
 34 |         }
    `----

Caused by:
    Syntax Error
```

Comment: `as` is from typescript, but you are using javascript

Comment: Thankyou for your reponse. I changed the file to typescript

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that `providers` is an array, and you are forcing it to behave as an object, pasting those `key:{value}` pairs inside:

```
callbacks: {
    jwt(params) {
      // update token
      if (params.user?.role) {
        params.token.role = params.user.role;
      }
      // return final_token
      return params.token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
```

To fix an error you need to wrap `key:{value}` pairs with `{ }`, so they can be one element of the array. As here:

```
export default NextAuth({
    
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({

        }),
        GithubProvider({

        }),
        CredentialsProvider({

        }),
        {
            callbacks: {

            },
            session: {

            },
            pages: {

            },
        }
    ],
    secret: "",
    debug: true
})
```